# How to access dynamic attributes in JSP (Struts2)

Tags: java, jsp, attributes, struts2, request

In Action I re set sent parameters.

```
    for(Enumeration<String> enumParams = request.getParameterNames(); enumParams.hasMoreElements();) {
        String name = enumParams.nextElement();
        String value = request.getParameter(name);
        request.setAttribute(name, value);
    }
```

On the JSP I would like to access the request attribute values.

```
<s:iterator value="variables">
    <input type="text" 
        id="<s:property value="sign"/>"
        name="<s:property value="sign"/>"  
        value="<s:property value="%{#attr['sign']}"/>" />
</s:iterator>
```

(variables are objects with field sign, etc.)

Currently I get with `<s:property value="%{#attr['sign']}"/>` only the sign of the variable, not the value. It does not evaulate `'sign'`.

Generated HTML:

```
<input id="A" name="A" value="A" type="text">
```

So if hard-code sign like this `<s:property value="%{#attr['A']}"/>`, I get the correct value...

Any clues? Please.

Comment: I didn't look at this closely but just note these things that trip people up: 1) 'A' is not a string but a character in OGNL, if OGNL gets more than one character in single quotes it will produce a string but a single character must use " characters. 2) Request parameters are not of type Map<String,String> but of Map<String,String[]> 3) A struts s:iterator tag can work with anything Iterable, so it can directly work with the #request map, this should be able to remove the action code (I think it is better to have code in the action than the view but in this case you'll still need to iterate).

Comment: Thanks for #1. By #2 we are careful (I hope enough :)). For #3 - yes it can, but here I am iterating through specific value objects, and if I would go and iterate also through request map, I would have O(n^2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little trick I got it:

```
<s:iterator value="variables">
    <s:set var="mySign" value="%{sign}" name="mySign" scope="request"></s:set>
    <jsp:useBean id="mySign" class="java.lang.String" scope="request" ></jsp:useBean>           
    <input type="text" 
        id="<s:property value="sign"/>"
        name="<s:property value="sign"/>"  
        value="<%=request.getAttribute(mySign)%>">
</s:iterator>
```